# .NET MVC 3 semantics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm reading some examples and i keep seeing code with [*SOMETHING*] before methods and I'd like to know what that's called and how it's used.

Can you define you own [*SOMETHING*] or is there a defined list of these things?

Here's some code examples I found that use this thing but don't explain anything about it.

```
[HandleError]

public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Sometimes they even put parameters in it too like

**[HandleError(Order = 2)]**

Whats going on here. I feel like this is **SUPER** important but none of the reference books I've read explain it they just use them.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HandleError` is an attribute.

**Brief Intro to Attributes**

Attributes are contained in square brackets, prefixing classes, structs, fields, parameters, functions, and arguments, and you can define your own by inheriting from Attribute in a class. The typical format of creating an attribute is as such:

```
public class NameOfYourAttributeAttribute : Attribute {

}
```

You can also prefix your attribute definition with an attribute that defines the scope of what it can apply to:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class | System.AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class NameOfYourAttributeAttribute : Attribute {

}
```

In the example above, there really isn't that much to the class, other than it just being a decorator for a class or a struct. Consider an example from the MSDN, where classes can be given an Author attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class | System.AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class Author : System.Attribute
{
    string name;
    public double version;

    public Author(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        version = 1.0;  // Default value
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

[Author("H. Ackerman")]
private class FirstClass
{
    // ...
}

// There's some more classes here, see the example link...

class TestAuthorAttribute
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PrintAuthorInfo(typeof(FirstClass));
        PrintAuthorInfo(typeof(SecondClass));
        PrintAuthorInfo(typeof(ThirdClass));
    }

    private static void PrintAuthorInfo(System.Type t)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Author information for {0}", t);
        System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t);  // reflection

        foreach (System.Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is Author)
            {
                Author a = (Author)attr;
                System.Console.WriteLine("   {0}, version {1:f}", a.GetName(), a.version);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In the case of HandleError, specifically:**

They provide helpful information that can be seen via reflection. In the case of `HandleError`, it means that if any exception is thrown within the controller, that it will render the Error view in ~/Views/Shared/.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx for more details.

Comment: Awesome answer. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

These are called [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287992%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and are a common feature of C#.
You can declare them yourself:

```
class SomeAttr : Attribute
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

They're called [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and they're just normal classes derived from `Attribute`. You can most certainly define your own.

Since MVC is made with convention over configuration in mind, you can decorate your functions with attributes and the framework will try to figure out what to do with them without any more intervention from you.

For example, if you decorate your function with `[HttpGet]`, only GET requests will get routed through it, anything else (like POST) will look for another function, or throw an error if nothing else is present.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]. I thought something like that was going on but its nice to see it explained.

Comment: Those two, together with `[Authorize]`, will get you through 90% of the attributes in MVC :)

Comment: Don't forget `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to help prevent Confused Deputy Attacks: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/anatomy-of-csrf-attack.aspx